# Issue on toggling of the SSR

Tags: c, for-loop, toggle, 8051

I am using Keil C to write my program. I have some problem which i have been stucked for ages and my program will toggle of the SSR(Solid State Relay) with a remote control. How my program works: Firstly, there is a Learn button which will will learn any Infrared Signal of the remote control and it will store in "DATA". When i press the remote control again, it will store the data into "TempDATA". My program will then compare both and check if there is an error or not. If there is no error, it will toggle the SSR and the Green LED will turn on. If there is any error, it will turn on the Red LED.

However, the problem is that, it will trigger 3 times instead of once. So, when there is no error, it will turn the SSR 'ON, OFF, ON'. If the remote control button is pressed again, the SSR will 'OFF, ON, OFF'. And if there are any error, it will display 'EEE' instead of 1 'E'. How do i solve this problem?

```
/***********************Problem Solved************************/
```

By adding a delay at:

```
while(1)
{  
    if(Data_Ready)                   //Data_Ready = 1
    {
               /*insert delay here*/
               Data_Ready = 0; 
               Result = 1;
               for(j=0;j<30;j++)              
               .
               .
               .
```

The problem is solved.

```
/****************************************MAIN*******************************************/
void main(void)
{   
unsigned char Result=0; 
unsigned int j;
unsigned int x =0;                              
TMOD = 0x21;          //Enable Timer 1 for 2nd Serial Port  & Timer0
TH1 = 0xFD;           //9600 Baud Rate
SCON0 = 0x50;        
SSR = 0;
Learn = 0;          
RedLED = 0;           
GreenLED= 0;

IE = 0x84;            //Enable External Interrupt 1                                                         
IT1 = 1;              //Set External Interrupt 1 to Edge Triggered.



while(1)
{  
    if(Data_Ready)                   //Data_Ready = 1
    {   
        Data_Ready = 0; 
        Result = 1;
        for(j=0;j<30;j++)                //Loop 30 times
        {
            if(DATA[j] != TempDATA[j])   //Compare DATA to TempDATA
            { 
                Result = 0;     
                break;                   //break from loop
            }               
        }//end for

        if(Result)                   
        {
            Result = 0;
            GreenLED = 1;            //Turn ON GreenLED
            RedLED = 0;              //Turn OFF RedLED

            SSR = ~SSR;              //Toggle SSR to ON and OFF


            SerialTx('S');
            SerialTx('S');
            SerialTx('R');

        }
        else
        {   
            Result = 0;
            RedLED = 1;              //Turn ON RedLED
            GreenLED = 0;            //Turn OFF GreenLED

            SerialTx('E');          //Print E on MTK to show Error       
        }

    }//end if
}//end while

}//end main
```

Data_Ready is set to 1 when i pressed the remote control button without pressing the Learn button. So it will only compare when i press the remote control button without pressing the Learn button.

Comment: have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: @MitchWheat Yep, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: as an aside, please don't comment a loop with "//Loop 30 times"

Comment: Do you have proper debouncing on the button?

Comment: @univerio Do you mean the Learn Button?

Comment: @xrainxfallx Well, both. Any button ought to be debounced.

Comment: @univerio Well, for the Learn button, I have to hold down the Learn button and press the remote control button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the

```
SSR=~SSR;
```

command. The first time, the initial state is already OFF. So on receiving correct data, it negates SSR making it ON. Then the three time sequence takes it to OFF and ON again. This corresponds to the first time situation when you get the right result.

Now, the next time correct data is received, SSR negates the previous state, which was already ON and the 3 time sequence would now be OFF=>ON=>OFF

So, what you could do here is to deliberately set the SSR to OFF state first before sending the next ON/OFF sequence.

(I haven't used Keil C, I have worked on AVR Studio for programming ATMEL uCs, so I can only do guesswork with the APIs used. But this answer is what I deduced from apparent logic)

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

---

Update:

does the Error[SerialTx('E')] give correct output?

I am assuming SSR has values like '0' or '1' or TRUE/FALSE.

So set SSR=0 (or something that turns it off) before the command SSR=~SSR, with a condition that it is executed only on the first sequence of your On=>Off=>On trigger. This would need a global static flag which saves the state of the sequence. For example,

```
static int sequence_in_progress = 0;
```

when the signal is received : sequence_in_progress +1
it will be incremented each time a signal is received.

Now, this can be used as a check to set the SSR to off if the correct signal is received for the first time:

```
if(sequence_in_progress==1)
{ SSR=0; //Or something that turns it off}

if(sequence_in_progress==3)
{sequence_in_progress=0;//reset it to zero every time your code finishes processing}
```

Comment: Even after removing the setting of SSR to 0, the problem is still there. And i forget 1 important part, which is that the Error [SerialTx('E')] will also trigger 3 times.

Comment: Check update in my answer, it uses a global flag to maintain the state of iteration and conditionally sets the SSR to OFF if the signal is received for the first time.

Comment: It seems like if i added a long delay (10s), it will only trigger once. I think the problem lies within the Toggling of the SSR.

Comment: Yes, seems like I missed something in the problem itself. The triggering part is okay, the problem is that it should be triggering once, but is triggering thrice.

This might be caused due to triggering of the Data_Ready which is flagged when data arrives. And since it triggers 3 times, all the three times, the data received is proper.

Try reducing the baud rate, ora s you said, introduce little delays.

Comment: Also, try reducing your buffer, 

what is the maximum size of the message (1 start bit+ 12 logic bits?)

Deliberately set your TempDATA[] array to zero after every readout, chances are, it is being re-read thrice before being discarded.

Comment: Well, it seems like adding delay will partially work as sometimes it will ON => OFF instead of just ON. Well, i have tried troubleshooting my program and found out that my Data_Ready is being triggered 3 times. Although the only way of triggering is only 1 way.

Comment: Reducing Baud Rate seems to result in error and clearing TempDATA[] will not work as well.

Comment: Aha, I have solved the problem. I added a small delay when the program enters If(Data_Ready) and it will only trigger once. Thanks for all your help.